Borrow some mutable value twice when the mutable value is known to be immutable
I have a construct similar to the following where the Analysis struct is responsible for analysing a file and the Project struct is responsible for managing files and dependencies that serves as a minimal reproducible example:
struct File;

trait Project {
    fn get_or_insert(&mut self) -> &File;
}

struct Analysis<'a> {
    project: &'a mut dyn Project
}

impl Analysis<'_> {
    fn analyze(&mut self) {
        let file = self.project.get_or_insert();
        self.analyze_parsed_file(file);
    }

    pub fn analyze_parsed_file(
        &mut self,
        file: &File
    ) {}

}

What I want to do is analyse a file. The project internally has an in-memory list of loaded files, but if the file I want to get is not inside that list, the project will load it from the disk and save it to that in-memory representation. The saving is necessary (in my case for cyclic dependency analysis).
The provided example does not compile because I am attempting to borrow self as mutable more than once. My rationale behind this is the following (but maybe that's already where my understanding of the borrow checker is at its limits):
If I call analyze_parsed_file, the function could modify file through the mutable reference to project. Therefore, the example is illegal in rust.
Now I know that this will never happen, because the project will never mutate files – it will only ever add them to the internal storage and it will not overwrite the file I just got.
Therefore, my question basically is: How do I tell this the borrow checker? Probably there are ways around this issue by using some form of unsafe, but I would rather stay in safe territory given that this seems to be a fairly straightforward use case. Is this where the ominous RefCell comes into play?

Does analyze_parsed_file() really need access to the project?

Yea, I guess that's the main issue :D. A file may contain dependencies and dependencies are managed by the Project. So inside analyze_parsed_file(), I might call get_or_insert() from the project. Just never on the file that should be analysed (because I consider self-imports illegal)

Assuming you could make Project::get_or_insert() take &self (ignore the difficulties for a moment), would your problems be solved? In other words, does analyze_parsed_file() needs mutable access to other parts of self than get_or_insert()?

I think I like where this is going. Yes, making Project::get_or_insert() take &self as parameter would solve the issue. The only reason I need a project to be mutable is because I want to insert something into the project during analysis of a file. No other mutable access is required.

As I said in the comments, you need to make Project::get_or_insert() takes &self instead of &mut self.
How do we do that, while it needs to mutate self?
The key is this:

the project will never mutate files – it will only ever add them to the internal storage and it will not overwrite the file I just got

If, for example, you store your files in a Vec - and assuming you have some form of indirection, e.g. Vec<Box<File>> (otherwise growing the Vec would invalidate all existing files) - you are good to go. But the compiler doesn't know that.
The solution is to use a special collection, a collection that pushes with shared references. Such collection is sound as long as it does not allow removal (it can allow it with mutable references, though). And it can be written using unsafe code.
Fortunately, you don't need to write that unsafe code - since someone else already did! Enter the elsa crate, that provides append-only collections of various kinds.
So, assuming you have for example Vec<Box<File>>, replace it with elsa::FrozenVec<Box<File>>, replace &mut self with &self, and that is all!

I think this is exactly what I want. Just to be sure, if I do want to remove elements using elsa (for example to prevent memory leaks), I would call elsa::FrozenVec::as_mut()::remove(...) to remove an element (just that this then needs a mutable reference, not just a shared one), correct?

@Schottky Indeed.

Not sure if there's a rust crate which provides one but you can also do append-only non-moving collections without indirection in the value by chaining in the collection e.g. unrolled linked lists (I think I've seen a variant where the node size is variable so it behaves more like a vector but that was in zig iirc), or trees (when the vector needs to "resize" you may have to increase the depth of the tree by adding new parent nodes, but the leaves don't get split). It does increase the lookup complexity though.

@Masklinn This is essentially an arena. typed-arena can provide one.
